# Удаление части строки со специальными символами

Tags: java, регулярные-выражения

У меня строки, по типу этой

```
{\pos(830,575)}{\hide18}In the promise you made at all
```

мне надо убрать тэг \hide, включая фигурные скобки

```
{\pos(830,575)}In the promise you made at all
```

Но мой код не может обработать знак '\'

```
String s = line.replaceAll( "{" + "\" + "hide" + type + "}", "");
```

Сколько бы я ни писал дополнительных знаков '\', это не работает, получаю     Illegal repetition

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Используйте

```
.replaceAll("\\{\\\\hide[^{}]*}", "")
```

См. [пример работы кода](https://ideone.com/tifKGf) и [демо регулярного выражения](https://regex101.com/r/Yh6SpJ/1).

**Подробности**

- `\{\\hide` - строка `{\hide`
- `[^{}]*`  - 0 и более символов, отличных от `{` и `}`
- `}` - символ `}`.